# FEA Simulation of CHASSIS

Tags: mechanical-engineering, structural-engineering, automotive-engineering, ansys

What are the most accurate methods in static state for simulation of chassis wrt 4 cases: lateral bending, torsion, head on collision and a zero turn. The problem arises when it comes to applying the boundary conditions for the simulation that is the fixtures and the forces acting. Any suggestions as to which method would be more accurate would help. The case here is a 4 wheeled vehicle with 2 mounting points on each side.

Comment: Can you please show a picture of what you are trying to design and what you struggle with?

Comment: "Head on collision" is not a *static* state.